# How to install .net on Windows CE 6.0 (Motorola)

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce, motorola

How to install .net on windows CE 6.0 Motorola device?
I tried copying files .net 2.0 and .net 3.5 still not working.
Please reply,  Thank you, 
MC

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply copy the framework folders from one machine to another, there's a lot more to .NET than just that. Even if you could, the framework that runs in mobile devices is not the same one that runs in Windows.

You need to download [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22808) and [that](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=65) (probably just the latter will do, though).

Comment: Hi,  Can anyone give me an answer I can apply, not just something out of the blue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My answer is one you can apply. The files in the links are the .NET installers you should use in Windows CE 6.0 devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Visual Studio 2008 with Mobile-Device-Development and Compact Framework, you will find the installation-files in this directory:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE

You need this one for CE: NETCFv35.wce.armv4.cab
And this one for Windows Mobile: NETCFv35.wm.armv4i.cab

Keep in mind that you can't use a higher version of Visual Studio at the moment.

Comment: Most links I've found lead to a .msi file download page. This is the .cab I was looking for. Thank you.